# Administrative installation - Controlling the output

Tags: command-line, windows-installer, installation

I'm trying to simply replace some files inside a folder, not really installing the app.
So I thought that I could use the `administrative` mode and `ADDLOCAL:Features` to achieve that.

The problem is that gives me no control on what and how it unpacks the files.
It will always unpack files to the `TARGETDIR` with this file structure:

```
* Parent Folder [the TARGETDIR]
   ⁁ MyApp.msi [almost empty MSI, with no files]
   * ProgramFilesFolder
       ⁁ All files that were inside of the installer
```

I understand the reasoning behind all this, but isn't there any way to control it?
For example, just unpacking the selected features, and without creating the *almost empty* MSI?

Comment: Please explain the need to to this better - this is not a good way. Administrative installation is just a glorified file extraction without much flexibility.

Comment: That's what I want, I file extraction via command. I'm using with as an auto-updater feature for a portable app. The updater downloads the installer, runs in "portable" mode, replacing the files that are needed.

It's already working, I just wanted to know if was possible to make it easier to handle.